# Sencha Touch 2 - Carousel initialize event firing in Chrome but not on Android-smartphone

Tags: android, sencha-touch, initialization, carousel, sencha-touch-2.2

In my ST2-app i create a panel which contains a carousel-element.
This carousel has to be filled dynamically with images from my store.

My problem is that the code shown below works fine in Chrome, but when i package my app and install it on my Galaxy S2, the initialize-event wont fire.

Has anyone a suggestion what could be the problem here?
I thought the browser androis is using is based on googles chrome-browser, so it should work the same.

Code:

```
createPanelBalloonSelect: function() {
    panelBalloonSelect = Ext.Viewport.add({            
        xtype: 'panel',

        centered: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        width: '90%',
        height: '70%',            
        modal: true,
        scope: this,

        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Auswahl Ballon',
                docked: 'top'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                id: 'myCarousel',
                flex: 1,

                items: [],

                config: {
                    initialize:  function() {
                        console.log('ich initialisiere!');
                        drawingsStore = Ext.getStore('drawingsStore');      
                        data = drawingsStore.getRange();

                        console.log('data: ' + data);

                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                            console.log('ich adde');

                            this.add({
                                xtype: 'image',                            
                                src: data[i].data.canvasData,
                                cls: 'card'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },

                defaults: {
                    listeners: {
                        activate: function(newActive, self, oldActive, opt) {
                            choosenBalloon = self.getActiveIndex();
                            console.log(choosenBalloon);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'OK',
                name: 'btnAcceptTemplate',
                scope: this,
                handler: function() {
                    this.setBalloonSrc(data[choosenBalloon].data.canvasData);
                    //this.drawBalloon();                        
                    this.initSzeneryCanvas();       
                    panelBalloonSelect.destroy();
                }
            }               
        ]            
    });           
},
```

Comment: Do u see any warnings in the chrome developer console?